# Updating State Object Does Not Rerender Dynamically Created Component

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, state, react-hooks

I have a component with three tabs in which I have unique filters for each tab. I am currently writing a Filter component that will take in the tab type as a prop and render the correct filter buttons. Upon clicking each button, I want that buttons styling to change so the user knows that they have set the given filter.

I am storing the state for each of the buttons in an object defined below:

```
const [filterState, setFilterState] = useState({
    deployment: {
      running: false,
      success: false,
      warnings: false,
      failures: false,
    },
    health: {
      warnings: false,
      critical: false,
      errors: false,
    },
    task: {
      waiting: false,
      running: false,
      retrying: false,
      success: false,
      failures: false,
    }
  })
```

I have a helper function used to set the filterType state defined as such:

```
  const setFilter = tab => {
    let updateFilter = filterState
    updateFilter[umsTab][tab] = !filterState[umsTab][tab]
    setFilterState(updateFilter)
    console.log(filterState[umsTab])
  }
```

I do this so that way I am fully updating the object state each time this function gets called. The function for updating the state gets called by the onClick method inside a Button component. These button components are dynamically created as I mentioned above, like so:

```
const createButtons = () => {
    let FilterButtons = []

    FilterTypes[umsTab].forEach(tab => {
      FilterButtons.push(
        <Button
          kind={filterState[umsTab][tab] === false ? "primary" : "secondary"}
          key={tab}
          onClick={() => setFilter(tab)}
        >
          {tab}
        </Button>
      )
    })

    return FilterButtons
  }
```

Clicking the button and logging the filterType state variable in the console shows that the state is updating, however the component is not rerendering. Could this enter code herebe due to the fact that the buttons are created dynamically? I am hoping that by checking the state object, I can render the buttons with or without stylization each time they are clicked.

The Full Code:

```
const FilterTypes = {
  deployment: ["running", "success", "warnings", "failures"],
  health: ["warnings", "critical", "errors"],
  task: ["waiting", "running", "retrying", "success", "failures"],
}

const Filters = ({ umsTab }: Props) => {
  const { message } = useMessages()
  const [filterState, setFilterState] = useState({
    deployment: {
      running: false,
      success: false,
      warnings: false,
      failures: false,
    },
    health: {
      warnings: false,
      critical: false,
      errors: false,
    },
    task: {
      waiting: false,
      running: false,
      retrying: false,
      success: false,
      failures: false,
    },
  })

  const setFilter = tab => {
    let updateFilter = filterState
    updateFilter[umsTab][tab] = !filterState[umsTab][tab]
    setFilterState(updateFilter)
    console.log(filterState[umsTab])
  }

  const createButtons = () => {
    let FilterButtons = []

    FilterTypes[umsTab].forEach(tab => {
      FilterButtons.push(
        <Button
          kind={filterState[umsTab][tab] === false ? "primary" : "secondary"}
          key={tab}
          onClick={() => setFilter(tab)}
        >
          {tab}
        </Button>
      )
    })

    return FilterButtons
  }

  return <div>{createButtons()}</div>
}
```

Comment: In your setFilter() helper function you should never set an object equal to another (objects are referenced) instead do const updateFilter = {...filterType}

Comment: This worked. Thanks for taking the time to look!

Comment: No problem glad it helped!

Answer (score 0):

Try to refactor the createButtons method to a Component function and provide the used fields as properties. When calling functions inside the rendering React can't check if something of the used values are changed and is not updating the ShadowDOM correctly

```
const CreateButtons = ({filterTypes, filterState, umsTab}) => (
<React.Fragment>
    {filterTypes[umsTab].map(tab => (
        <Button
          kind={filterState[umsTab][tab] === false ? "primary" : "secondary"}
          key={tab}
          onClick={() => setFilter(tab)}
        >
          {tab}
        </Button>
      ))
    }
</React.Fragment>
)
```

and in Filters

```
return <div><CreateButtons filterTypes={FilterTypes} filterState={filterState} umsTab={umsTab}/></div>
```